# Scrubbing does not work on playing a network stream video vlcj

Tags: vlc, vlcj

We are having the same issue that is descibed here https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/4888

When we try to scrubbing the video, it does not work, vlcj is buffering every time we scrubbing and we are getting the errors logs below

```
[163bdd44] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 101 ms)
[163bdd44] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called

[2403dc04] core vout display error: Failed to set on top

[164a8284] http access error: error: HTTP/1.1 500 Object not found

[5:56] 
[15c5f1d4] core input error: input control fifo overflow, trashing type=3
```

Does anyone know if using a convention of [VLC Configuration](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) we can fix it ?

Thanks
Francisco

Comment: well, how are you doing the scrubbing? are you just sending a whole load of unthrottled seek API calls one after the other? it is your application that is in control of the seeking, not vlcj.

Comment: Hi team, we are using https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player project,       
the way is implemented, they are calling  mediaPlayer.setPosition(source.getValue() / 1000.0f); every time the user move the JSlider bar, source.getValue() is the % where the JSlider is at. Could you guys help us to find a better solution, we do not have a lot of experience, sorry if we are asking something that is 
obvious

Comment: we also know about this event, but not sure if it can help 
  mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
       @Override
    public void buffering(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, float newCache) {
     
     
 } }